Why I have to submit the CRUD twice for it to take affect
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import {
  DataGridPro,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridToolbarExport,
  GridToolbarColumnsButton,
  GridToolbarDensitySelector,
  GridActionsCellItem,
  GridRowModes,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro"
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  LinearProgress,
  Snackbar,
  Typography,
  Tooltip,
} from "@mui/material"
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit"
import SaveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Save"
import CancelIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close"
import ToggleOnIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ToggleOn"
import ToggleOffIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ToggleOff"
import moment from "moment"
import Cookies from "js-cookie"

const reportingEndpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT_QA_REPORTING

// Function to display a full-featured CRUD data grid
function FullFeaturedCrudGrid() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([])
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [showIcons, setShowIcons] = useState(true)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState(null)

  // Obtain OT data from the server
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${reportingEndpoint}/fst/schedule/ot`)
      .then((response) => {
        setRows(response.data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error)
        setLoading(false)
      })
  
    fetchUserDetails() // Call fetchUserDetails after the component mounts
  }, [])
  
  // Function to handle the edit button click
 const handleEditClick = (id) => () => {
   const currentRowData = rows.find((row) => row.id === id) // Find the row data for the given ID
   setRowModesModel({
     ...rowModesModel,
     [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, originalData: currentRowData }, // Set the row mode to Edit
   })
 }

// Function to handle the save button click
const handleSaveClick = (id) => () => {
  const rowToUpdate = rows.find((row) => row.id === id) // Find the row data for the given ID
  if (!rowToUpdate) { // If the row data is not found, log an error and return
    console.error("Row data not found for ID:", id) // Log an error message
    return
  }

  // Get user display name
  const modifiedBy = userDetails?.displayName || 'Unknown User' // Use the user's display name if available, otherwise set to 'Unknown User'
  const modified = new Date().toISOString() // Get the current timestamp in ISO format

  // Add user details and modification date to the data being updated
  const dataToUpdate = {
    overtimeLength: rowToUpdate.overtimeLength,
    reason: rowToUpdate.reason,
    comments: rowToUpdate.comments,
    modifiedBy: rowToUpdate.modifiedBy || modifiedBy,
    modified: rowToUpdate.modified || modified,
  }

  console.log("Data being sent to the server for update:", dataToUpdate)
 
  // Send the updated data to the server for processing
  axios
    .put(`${reportingEndpoint}/fst/schedule/ot/${id}`, dataToUpdate) // Send a PUT request to update the row data
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Received response from the server:", response)
      if (response.status === 200) { // If the response status is 200 (OK)
        const updatedRows = rows.map((row) => // Update the rows state with the modified row data
          row.id === id ? { ...row, ...dataToUpdate } : row // Update the row data if the ID matches
        )
        setRows(updatedRows) // Update the rows state with the modified row
        setRowModesModel((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View }, // Set the row mode to View after saving
        }))
        console.log("Row updated successfully with data:", dataToUpdate) // Log a success message
        alert("Row updated successfully!")
      } else {
        alert("Failed to update row: unexpected server response.")
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Failed to update row:", error)
      alert(`Failed to update row: ${error.message || "Server error"}`)
    })
}

// Function to handle the cancel button click
const handleCancelClick = (id) => () => {
  const originalData = rowModesModel[id]?.originalData // Get the original data for the row
  if (originalData) {
    setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === id ? originalData : row))) // Reset the row data to the original data
  }
  setRowModesModel((prev) => { // Update the row mode to View
    const updatedModel = { ...prev }
    delete updatedModel[id]
    return updatedModel
  })
  }
  

// Function to handle the row update process
const processRowUpdate = (newRow) => {
  setRows((prevRows) => prevRows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? newRow : row)))
  return newRow
}


// Obtain current logged in user information
const fetchUserDetails = async () => {
  const ssoEndpoint = process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT_QA_SSO
  const token = Cookies.get("token")
  setIsLoading(true)
  // Check if the access token is available in the cookies
  if (!token) {
    console.error("Access token is not available.")
    setIsLoading(false)
    return
  }
// Fetch user details from the server using the access token
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${ssoEndpoint}/user-details`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
    if (response.data) {
      setUserDetails(response.data)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch user details:", error)
    setUserDetails({}) // Ensure userDetails is set to an empty object on error
  } finally {
    setIsLoading(false)
  }
}

  const CustomToolbar = () => (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <Tooltip title="Toggle Icons">
        <Button color="primary" onClick={() => setShowIcons(!showIcons)}>
          {showIcons ? (
            <>
              <ToggleOnIcon sx={{ marginRight: 1, color: "green" }} />
              <Typography variant="body2">Icons</Typography>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <ToggleOffIcon sx={{ marginRight: 1, color: "red" }} />
              <Typography variant="body2">Icons</Typography>
            </>
          )}
        </Button>
      </Tooltip>
      <GridToolbarExport
        sx={{
          color: "#0c51a1",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }}
      />
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton
        sx={{
          color: "#ffa600",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }}
      />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector
        sx={{
          color: "#1b9ddb",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }}
      />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  )


  const columns = [
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      headerName: "Actions",
      width: 150,
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit
        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<SaveIcon
              sx={{ color: "green" }}
              />}
              label="Save"
              onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<CancelIcon
                sx={{ color: "red" }}
              />}
              label="Cancel"
              onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
            />,
          ]
        }
        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<EditIcon
            sx={{ color: "#ffc72c" }}
            />}
            label="Edit"
            onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
          />,
        ]
      },
    },
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 80 },
    {
      field: "date",
      headerName: "Date",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) =>
        moment(params.row.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS A"),
    },
    {
      field: "jurisdiction",
      headerName: "Jurisdiction",
      width: 150,
    },
    {
      field: "fstNumber",
      headerName: "FST Number",
      width: 150,
    },
    {
      field: "emailAddress",
      headerName: "Email Address",
      width: 200,
    },
    {
      field: "displayName",
      headerName: "Display Name",
      width: 200,
    },
    { field: "manager", headerName: "Manager", width: 150 },
    {
      field: "dateWorked",
      headerName: "Date Worked",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) =>
        moment(params.row.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS A"),
    },
    {
      field: "overtimeLength",
      headerName: "Overtime Length",
      width: 150,
      type: "number",
      editable: true,
    },
    { field: "penalty", headerName: "Penalty", width: 100},
    {
      field: "reason",
      headerName: "Reason",
      width: 150,
      editable: true,
      type: "singleSelect",
      valueOptions: [
        "Administrative",
        "Depot Coverage",
        "Depot Repair",
        "Down Call",
        "Drive Home",
        "High Jackpots",
        "Holiday Coverage",
        "Urgent Removal Request - Ad-hoc",
        "Lottery Special Events",
        "NOC Repoints /ASI Calls",
        "On-Site / Off-site Meeting",
        "Other",
        "Out-of-State Project",
        "Phone Support (On-call assist)",
        "Penalty Call",
        "Project (other)",
        "Site Project",
        "Software Issues",
        "Staffing / Field Coverage",
        "Standby / Service Call Coverage",
        "Training",
        "Travel",
        "Vacation Coverage",
        "Vehicle Issues / Breakdowns",
        "Weather-related",
      ],
    },
    {
      field: "comments",
      headerName: "Comments",
      width: 200,
      editable: true,
    }, 
    // {
    //   field: "modifiedBy",
    //   headerName: "Modified By",
    //   width: 200,
    //   editable: true,

    // }, 
    // {
    //   field: "modified",
    //   headerName: "Modified",
    //   width: 200,
    //   editable: true,
    // }
  ]

  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPro
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        onProcessRowUpdateError={(error) =>
          console.error(`Error processing row update: ${error}`)
        }
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
        }}
        loading={loading}
        editMode="row"
        rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
        onRowModesModelChange={setRowModesModel}
      />
    </Box>
  )
}

export default FullFeaturedCrudGrid

I have updated and fixed my state in my code. Additionally I cleared my React cache to see if that was the issue. Here is a console log:
Data being sent to the server for update: {overtimeLength: 31, reason: 'Down Call', comments: 'Testing CRUD 15', modifiedBy: 'user, test', modified: '2024-05-07T14:04:08.000Z'}
overtimeDataGrid.js:91 Received response from the server: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
overtimeDataGrid.js:101 Row updated successfully with data: {overtimeLength: 31, reason: 'Down Call', comments: 'Testing CRUD 15', modifiedBy: 'user, test', modified: '2024-05-07T14:04:08.000Z'}
overtimeDataGrid.js:85

 Data being sent to the server for update: {overtimeLength: 37, reason: 'Out-of-State Project', comments: 'Testing CRUD 15', modifiedBy: 'user, test', modified: '2024-05-07T14:04:08.000Z'}
overtimeDataGrid.js:91 Received response from the server: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
overtimeDataGrid.js:101 Row updated successfully with data: {overtimeLength: 37, reason: 'Out-of-State Project', comments: 'Testing CRUD 15', modifiedBy: 'user, test', modified: '2024-05-07T14:04:08.000Z'}

